# "Authorization" is better written in dot notation.eslintdot-notation problem in Vuejs

Tags: authentication, vuejs2, axios

I want to add a default axios authorization bearer token in vuejs application:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${userData.token}`
```

It is now looks `["Authorization"] is better written in dot notation.eslintdot-notation` .
When I want to save it, it changes to

```
`axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${userData.token}`
```

It is not working. What is the problem with?